# How can I play raw PCM file that I dumped from a codec?

Tags: debugging, vlc, playback, pcm

I'm debugging an audio codec and need to test if the data is coming out of a codec properly.  I have my code dumping the raw pcm stream into a file and now I want to try to play it in VLC or another OS X compatible player.  I've heard that this is possible with VLC from the command line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short of writing some code to output your own header followed by your PCM data which will of course work - you could use [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) to import the file as RAW data where you then specify :

```
Encoding : signed 16 bit PCM
Byte order : little endian (typically unless you're on powerpc or such)
Channels : 1 mono
start offset : 0
sample rate 44100 Hz (typical)
```

once imported Audacity will let you play the clip ... not as slick as some command line but easy to do none the less

this also works

```
ffplay  -autoexit -f s16le  myrawaudio.pcm
```

above assumes your raw audio is using bit depth of 16 bits which is typical of CD quality audio

Comment: This is incredibly convenient for playing back the raw PCM output of Android's AudioRecord API. Thanks!